# Visual Studio 2008 with SSIS and SSRS options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis, ssrs-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I downloaded Visual Studio 2008 from Microsoft.

Visual Studio 2008: (3,30 GB) http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso

Final objective is to use SQL Server agent to execute SSIS tasks and later build an ASP.NET website to show SSRS reports.

After Visual Studio installation, I can't find SSIS and SSRS options inside.

I know SSIS and SSRS is part of SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard installation. Any idea how I can include it in my Visual Studio as an add on ? My SQL Server is running on another server. If I install VS which part of the SQL Server installation, I don't have the ASP.Net option.

Hope you can give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run the SQL Server installation and look for the component:
Business Intelligence Development Studio add-ins to Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any ISO for SQL Server 2008R2 and have been using this one from Microsoft.

This download comes as a pre-configured VHD. This download enables you evaluate SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition VHD for 180 days.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26113

Comment: I know SSIS is available in the sql server express edition you can download.  Not sure about SSRS.

Comment: Part of SSRS features are supported in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services. Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx#Reporting